# Elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and prove it's simple group

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group, simple-groups

I'm trying to understand properties of groups. Since $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ ($p$ is prime)
is quotient group It should be set of all left cosets of $p\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ which is,

> $ \{ m+pn \mid m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $

Then I set an $H\subseteq p\mathbb{Z}$.Then it must satisfy,

> $ \forall h_1,h_2\in H:h_1h_2^{-1} \in H$

I'm stuck here. I don't what to do. Please help me.

Comment: What is $H$  and $h^{-1}$?  Is the addition operation in your group?

Comment: I guess you are stuck about what $h_2^{-1}$ is when $h_2$ is a set? If so, then think of it a operating on *every* element of $h_2$, any why it does not make a difference on what element.

Comment: Hint: Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. The Lagrange theorem says that  $\mathrm{card} H$ is  a divisor of $p$, i.e. $H$ has $1$ or $p$ elements (since $p$ is a prime). What is $H$ if it has one element? What if it has $p$ elememnts (Do not forget $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ has $p$ elements) ?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Another method is directly showing that if $H$ contains an element other than $0+\mathbb{Z}$, then $H=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$: Assume $a+p\mathbb{Z}\in H$, $p\not\mid a$. Since $H$ is a subgroup, for arbitrary $n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$,
\begin{equation*}
\overbrace{(a+p\mathbb{Z})+\cdots+(a+p\mathbb{Z})}^{\text{$n$ times}}\in H.
\end{equation*}
That is $na+p\mathbb{Z}\in H$. For any $b+p\mathbb{Z}\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, can you show exists $n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ s.t. $na+p\mathbb{Z}=b+p\mathbb{Z}$? (That is equivalent to $p\mid na-b$, which is immediate from Bezut's theorem.)

Comment: "set of all left cosets of $p\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ which is,$ \{ m+pn \mid m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $": no, it is not a set of integers. It is a set of *sets of* integers: $ \{ m+p\Bbb Z \mid m\in \mathbb{Z} \} $ (and each $m+p\Bbb Z$ is $ \{ m+pn \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $).

Answer (score -1):

The elements are each of the form

$$[a]_p:=\{b\in\Bbb Z: p\mid a-b\}$$

for $a\in \Bbb Z$; so: $$[0]_p, [1]_p, \dots, [p-1]_p.$$

It's simple due to Lagrange's Theorem: since $p$ is prime, the only subgroups of $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ are the trivial ones.